# Difference between NSArray and NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsarray

What is the difference b/w `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: Be nice... we all have to start somewhere, and the docs can be very cryptic to a newcomer.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

`NSMutableArray` (and all other classes with `Mutable` in the name) can be modified. So, if you create a plain `NSArray`, you cannot change its contents later (without recreating it). But if you create an `NSMutableArray`, you can change it — you'll notice it has methods like `-addObject:` and `-insertObject:atIndex:`.

See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/) for details.

Answer (score 5):

The "mutable" types are classes which can be changed after they've been initialized, like `NSMutableString` vs `NSString`.

Comment: `NSMutableString` is derived from `NSString`. Consequently, you can't rely on a "`NSString*`" you receive from outside to be immutable. You can only assume `NSMutableString*` is mutable. `NSString*` can be mutable or immutable. That's why you might want to call `[str copy]` when the instance is assigned to some property in your class.

Comment: You can't change an NSString once it's built. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905396/the-final-word-on-nsstrings-mutable-and-immutable. As for why you use copy, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain

Comment: Shaggy: You can't change an *instance* of `NSString` class. This is not the issue. The issue is that a "`NSString*`" does not necessarily point to an instance of `NSString` class. It can also point to instances of classes derived from `NSString`, like `NSMutableString`. Therefore, you can't rely on an `NSString*` you have received from the outside world to be immutable.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. I'll delete that portion of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

NSArray : in NSArray we can not change index....
          Means fix array.

NSMutableArray : in NSMutableArray we can change index and also add the value in array at run-time..