# Objective-c string appending causes exception

Tags: objective-c

The following code is causing me some problems. The third line causes a program crash... it doesn't happen the first time I step through but somehow later on in the program.  If I comment out that third line, the program runs smoothly.

```
NSString *myRequestString = @"text";
int i = 1;
myRequestString = [myRequestString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"t=%d", i]];
```

That code causes this exception:

`*** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xb4c43fe0`

On a side note, can anyone tell me how to concatenate strings in objective-c like any other normal language... I can't believe that there is no concatenation operator.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You know, you can use `-stringByAppendingFormat:`.

Comment: thanks for that tip, switched it over but I still get the exception.

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is coming from that line, or is it elsewhere in your code? It's indicating you (or something) is calling `[someString release]` after `someString` has already been de-allocated (ref. count is 0). 

Also, you are leaking the original instance of `myRequestString` since `stringByAppendingString` returns a *new* instance of `NSString`. You can fix that with `myRequestString = [[myRequestString autorelease] stringByAppending......]`

Comment: @Michael: If the original string is a constant string, it's not a leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're releasing `myRequestString` at some point without retaining it, which is not correct [according to the memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/).

And no, there's no concatenation operator. There isn't one in C either.

Answer (score -1):

You need a [NSMutableString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/index.html) to do that:

```
NSMutableString *myRequestString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
[myRequestString appendString:@"text"];
int i = 1;
myRequestString = [myRequestString appendFormat: @"t=%d", i];
```

Don't forget: [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/) [is immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905396/the-final-word-on-nsstrings-mutable-and-immutable).

Comment: What do you mean "you need NSMutableString to do that"? NSString works just fine the way he's doing it — it won't do an in-place append, but it will work just fine. He's just not managing his memory correctly at some point. If you use an autoreleased NSMutableString, it will blow up in the same way.