# NSString is really Immutable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Why when I code I can do:

```
NSString *test;

test = @"stack";
test = @"overflow";
```

without any problems, `NSString` is not supposed to be immutable?

Comment: If it was already mutable, then why would we have NSMutableString?  

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [The final word on NSStrings: Mutable and Immutable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905396/the-final-word-on-nsstrings-mutable-and-immutable)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *is* immutable. You're not changing the underlying string with those statements, you're creating/using a brand new string. The pointer itself can change as often as you want but that's not the string.

Comment: And it's ok to do this or it's the wrong way to manipulate string.

Comment: It is the correct way to handle it.  Whenever you do @"Some Text" you are really just creating an autoreleased instance of NSString.

Comment: Ok, so when you use NSMutableString if you can do this with NSString, sorry if my question feels stupid.

Comment: @alex, there are no stupid questions, the pursuit of knowledge is rarely a bad thing. One reason you'd use a mutable string is if you didn't want to burden the garbage collector (GC takes time and fragmented memory can be a performance issue). Example: say you have a string that's always of the form 'User:14860' and the only thing that changes is the '14860' bit. You can use a mutable string and just change that bit (assuming length of '14860' is the same) which will not result in any objects becoming garbage-collectable. If instead you kept creating new strings, memory would soon fragment.

Comment: Actually, if he's working on the iPhone garbage collection really doesn't come into this.  In his case, he'd need to worry about autoreleased strings piling up in an autorelease pool (particularly within a tight loop) or manually managing the memory for each.  Also, object allocation / deallocation is one of the most expensive operations you can perform on the iPhone, and you can avoid that using a mutable string.

Answer (score 7):

The string object is immutable.  You are only changing the pointer to a different string.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you just "forget" about the old value (stack) and create a new string instance and fill it with "overflow"...